# How to get the asked columns for each customers

Tags: sql

I have this table called table a

[image]

I need to get the CustomerID, sum(Income) of 2015, sum(Income) of 2016, did he ever bought productId A (boolean), is the total sum(income)> 1000 (boolean), number of total InvoiceID

all that in one query and the results should be with 1 row per customer.

please help I don't even know how to start!

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Please provide a working SQL fiddle with example data and what you've attempted.  Also specify what database engine you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically conditional aggregation:

```
select customerid,
       sum(case when extract(year from date) = 2015 then sales end) as sales_2015,
       sum(case when extract(year from date) = 2016 then sales end) as sales_2016,
       max( product = 'A' ) as ever_bought_a,
       sum(income) > 1000 as sum_exceeds_1000,
       count(*) as num_invoices
from t
group by customerid;
```

You haven't specified a database, so this is really psuedocode.  You'll need to adapt it for your particular database.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please explain to me how the max(product "A") giving me if customers ever bought product a?   Also, how sum(income) > 1000 is giving me  boolean answer to if he bought for more  than 1000?

Comment: @AviCohen . . . In a database that supports booleans -- which your question presupposes -- `max()` of a boolean value is equivalent to an aggregate `or`.